From script to plugin (roadoffsetter)
Where am I wrong? help pls. Original script is here https://admon2nd.gumroad.com/l/abysr
I wanna get a plugin from the script.
The error when I am applying the modifier (Maximum nested error dialog depth reached - Attempt to display more than maximum number of simultaneous...)
plugin simpleMeshMod roadoffsetterPlag
name:"roadoffsetter"
classID:#(0x6d66486, 0x5a586671)
version:1
category:"MXS Help"
(
  parameters main rollout:roadoffsetter
  (
        NumL_spn1 ui:spn1 default:1 type:#integer animatable:true
        L_Width_spn2 ui:spn2 default:10 type:#worldunits animatable:true 
        YL_Dist_spn3 ui:spn3 default:1 type:#worldunits animatable:true
    )

rollout roadoffsetter "Road Offsetter 1.1" width:180
(
    
    spinner spn1 "Number of Lanes :" width:60 range:[1,100,1] type:#integer --align:#right
    spinner spn2 "Lane Width :" width:60 range:[0,1000,10] type:#worldunits --align:#right
    spinner spn3 "Yellow Lines Dist. :" width:60 range:[0,1000,1] type:#worldunits --align:#right
    checkbox chk1 " Enable Yellow Lanes" offset:[0,5]
    checkbox chk2 " Flip Direction"
    checkbox chk3 " Spline is Road Center"
    
    --button btn1 "Offset it !" width:160 height:24 offset:[0,5]
    hyperLink web "3D_R.n.D Tools and Models" address:"https://linktr.ee/3D_R.n.D" offset:[0,5]
    label cRight "Copyright 2021"
)   
    local thespline, spl, allspl, selspl, opened,  y, f, v, v2, vy, fo, aa, aa1, t
    --( FUNCTIONS
    fn CreateShp arr id = (
        s = splineshape()
        addnewspline s
        
        for i = 1 to arr.count do addKnot s 1 arr[i][1] #curve arr[i][2] arr[i][3] arr[i][4]
            
        toid = numSegments s 1
        for ii = toid to 1 by -1 do (
        setMaterialID  s 1 ii id
        )
        updateShape s
        s
    )
    fn Apply_Offset shp f id  weld:true opened:true shp1: = (
        local s
        applyOffset shp f
        if not opened then (
            deleteSpline shp 1 
            toid = numSegments shp 1
            for ii = toid to 1 by -1 do (
            setMaterialID  shp 1 ii id
        )
            )else (
            local n = numKnots shp
            local arr = for i = (n/2)+1 to n collect #(getKnotType shp 1 i,getKnotPoint shp 1 i,getInVec  shp 1 i,getOutVec shp 1 i)
            s = CreateShp arr id
            delete shp
        )
        if weld then if s != undefined then addAndWeld shp1 s 0 else addAndWeld shp1 shp 0
            else if s != undefined then s  else shp
        
    )
    fn Delete_Spline shp j  chk:true = (
        a = copy shp
        spl = getSplineSelection a
        allspl = numSplines a
        if chk do (
        spl0 = getSplineSelection shp
        deleteSpline shp spl0[j]
            )
        for i = allspl to 1 by -1 do (
            if i != spl[j] do deleteSpline a i
        )
        a
    )
    --)

    on  modifyMesh do  (
        if selection.count == 1 and canConvertTo $ SplineShape do with undo on (
            thespline = $
            convertToSplineShape thespline
            selspl = getSplineSelection thespline
            allspl = numSplines thespline
            if selspl.count == 0 do (t = allspl ; selspl = #{1..allspl} as array
                setsplineselection thespline selspl)
            t = selspl.count
            for ii = t to 1 by -1 do (
                max create mode
                opened = not (isClosed thespline selspl[1])
                if chk1.state then y = 2 else y = 0
                if chk2.state then f = -1 else f = 1    
                for i = 1 to allspl do setSegSelection thespline i #()
                v = L_Width_spn2*f
                v2 = L_Width_spn2*f
                vy = YL_Dist_spn3.value*f
                fo1 = ((NumL_spn1*v)+vy*2)/2
                fo2 = (NumL_spn1*v)/2
                                    

                if chk1.state then fo = fo1 else fo = fo2
                chk = chk3.state
                aa1 = Delete_Spline thespline ii  chk:chk
                if chk do (
                    if not opened do fo = -1 * fo
                    aa2 = Apply_Offset aa1 fo 1  weld:false opened:opened 
                    aa1 = copy aa2
                    addAndWeld thespline aa2 0
                    )
                
                -------------------------------------- yellow option
                
                if y == 2 then (
                    
                    aa = copy aa1
                    Apply_Offset aa vy 3  weld:true opened:opened shp1:thespline
                    v2 = (v2 + vy)
                    for j = 1 to NumL_spn1 do (
                        aa = copy aa1
                        if j != NumL_spn1 then Apply_Offset aa v2 2  weld:true opened:opened shp1:thespline
                        else Apply_Offset aa v2 3  weld:true opened:opened shp1:thespline
                        v2 = (v2 + v)
                    )
                    v2 = (v2 +- v + vy)
                    Apply_Offset aa1 v2 1  weld:true opened:opened shp1:thespline
                )
                ---------------------------------------yellow option end
                else (
                    for j = 1 to NumL_spn1 do (
                        if j != NumL_spn1 then (
                            aa = copy aa1
                        
                            Apply_Offset aa v2 2  weld:true opened:opened shp1:thespline
                            
                        )
                        else Apply_Offset aa1 v2 1  weld:true opened:opened shp1:thespline
                        v2 = (v2 + v)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        ------------------operation ends here
        updateshape thespline
        max modify mode
        --subobjectLevel = 3
    )
)

I wanna get a plugin from the script
